# How to implement InApp purchase in the TVOS application which is made up using TVML and TVJS and removing storyboard?

Tags: in-app-purchase, tvos, tvml

I am working on the TVOS application. I have to add Inapp Purchase for my product. 
I made this application using TVML and TVJS so that I removed all the storyboard content. My problem is that, What is the possible solution to implement the InApp Purchase in this scenario. In addition type of purchase is Non-renewing subscriptions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to make it inside the App (using Swift or Objective-C) and create a class to expose some methods to TVMLJS.

In your TVML code you can just call a method and listen for some events from the App to present the correct message to the user.

More information how to create this bridge you can take a look in the JSExport Protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/JavaScriptCore/Reference/JSExport_Ref/index.html

**Update:**

NSHipster has a complete tutorial about that:

http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. If you have any sample, please provide me that will help me to understand more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: I have added a link for NSHipster with a tutorial about that. If you have already implemented InApp Purchase in any other App, probably will be easy to connect it with TVML